# JavaScript knockout gives same value to another label

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

javascript knockout if I click on the plus sign at materials then the name of the label below changes to the genes I clicked on and this is not possible and it also happens when I click on materials of the bottom data I use in my knouckout target push but I can't find the error

```js
target.add = function (item, event) {
            target.push(ko.observable(new Object()));
            if (target.currentPage() > target.pageCount())
                target.moveLast(item, event);

            $j.each($j('tr.accordion', 'table[data-table = ' + _tableName + ']'), function ()
            {
                if ($j(this).next('tr.checkIfEmpty').is(":visible"))
                    $j(this).click();
            });
```

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC74v.png)
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOqOK.png)

Comment: Side note: There's basically never any reason to use `new Object()`. Use `{}` instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have 
tried this doesn't help

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?